# Whilst or while, etc - Oxford Spelling

Tags: word-choice, academia, style-manuals

I am writing an academic paper and would like to use the Oxford spelling throughout. (I am native British.) I read that Oxford spelling generally follows British English other than a few exceptions, such as *-ize* (*-ization*) instead of *-ise* (*-isation*). I have not managed to come across rules for the words "whilst/while" and "amongst/among", with the prior of the two commonly used in British English.

Which would be correct to use according to the Oxford spelling?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I choose between "while" and "whilst"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16319/how-do-i-choose-between-while-and-whilst)

Comment: The [University of Oxford Style Guide](https://www.ox.ac.uk/sites/files/oxford/media_wysiwyg/University%20of%20Oxford%20Style%20Guide.pdf) contains 'She couldn’t decide among all the colleges.' (this as an incidental example showing in part the different usages of 'between' and 'among') It also advises elsewhere to minimise the use of ink where clarity is not compromised.

Comment: Also: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/2157/191178

Comment: @Laurel I stated that I know they are essentially interchangeable (bar using while in some cases) and that one is preferred in British English, but the question is which (if so) does the Oxford spelling request?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth This is interesting, though the article contains the heading "Capitalisation", whereas, the Oxford spelling would require "Capitalization" instead. I assume this is a general university style guide rather than Oxford spelling.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth My comment relates to the use that British universities commonly prefer to use "public English" rather than "Oxford English", even if this was published from Oxford University.

Comment: Right. You need to look at usage notes under the specific entries in OED (which _does_ use 'Oxford spelling')  then for advice (eg caveats such as 'rare' / 'archaic'). I'm not sure they'll go as far as 'don't use these old-fashioned variants'. If they have different headwords, OED surely doesn't consider them as mere spelling variants.

Comment: Isn't this like asking "which is the correct spelling: *burned* or *burnt*."  The words *whilst* and *while* are both pronounced and spelt differently.

Answer (score 1):

It's more important to be consistent (even if you're consistently using *while* for one context and *whilst* for another), but in short the answer is

### While

[Oxbridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxbridge) English is of course definitionally [British English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_English) and, if anything, the [prestige dialect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_Pronunciation). The house style of [Oxford University Press](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_University_Press) (as well as [*Nature*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nature_(journal))) is likewise definitionally a form of British English.

Your specific examples are understandable but badly taken. The spelling *civilization* [is **more** common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=civilization%2Ccivilisation&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3) than *civilisation* in British publications (in addition to [being more etymologically & phonetically accurate](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/80600/171986), not that [any form of English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50699/which-flavor-of-english-british-vs-american-first-had-standard-modern-spellin) ever *really* cares about that); the spelling *while* is [**vastly more** common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=while%2Cwhilst&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3) than *whilst* in British English (and always has been); the spelling *among* is [**just as vastly** more common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=among%2Camongst&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3) than *amongst* in British English (and likewise always has been). There's [a general sense](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/244578/171986) that *civilisation*, *whilst*, *amongst*, *stone*, *tonne*, & all are **non-American** but, whilst that may be helpful to marketers trying to make their products [sound especially Britishy](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SfWR0PeEnTM), it doesn't necessarily reflect the actual speech of actual Britons.

In any case, even though that should already be enough to reconcile you with Oxford's "Americanized" British English (which was always just its own), the [2014 style guide](https://www.ox.ac.uk/public-affairs/style-guide) already linked above and the [present (2016) version](https://www.ox.ac.uk/sites/files/oxford/University%20of%20Oxford%20Style%20Guide%20%28updated%20Hilary%20term%202016%29.pdf) available from the University's [Public Affairs site](https://www.ox.ac.uk/public-affairs/style-guide) noticeably use *while* and *among* repeatedly while eschewing either *whilst* or *amongst*. As Mr Ashworth already noted, that's in keeping with their own guidance to write as tersely and clearly as possible. Similarly, using Google to search crawled sites available at the domain [www.oup.com](http://www.oup.com), there are occasional instances of *whilst* but many, many more of *while*.

Comment: Please remove the apparent compound _Oxbridge English_ which is not a recognised term and will confuse as _Oxford English_ **is** a recognised term.

Comment: That makes no sense whatsoever. There is already a link directly to the fact that it _is_ a recognized term. Avail yourself of it or hie yourself to [the OED](https://oed.com/view/Entry/135559).

Comment: That said, sure, you're right that the more careful linguistic classification would be East Midlands dialect. That's more descriptive of geography than social class or education, though. RP is more common still but again aside the point of what we're talking about here.

Comment: I find no mention of the apparent compound 'Oxbridge English' at the linked article.  As an alumnus of the older establishment, I'm well aware of the portmanteau 'Oxbridge'. And of the established compound 'Oxford English'. Would you like to reconsider, and remove the unwarranted smart comment?

Comment: Oxford spelling is associated specifically with Oxford University and not at all with Cambridge. So while Oxbridge is a thing, Oxbridge spelling is not.

Comment: @rchivers You're quite right, but I didn't say it was. Mr Ashworth's point is much better taken, but that was already addressed.

Answer (score 1):

> Which would be correct to use according to the Oxford spelling?

The OED gives

> **whilst**, adverb and conjunction (and preposition) = **while** conjunction (and preposition)

The adverbial use is marked as "obsolete or dialect." Hence the words are the same.

The "rule" is thus "Use whichever you want, but be consistent."

Answer (score -2):

Both are correct in their context. Normally, in academic writing there is no strict requirement unless stated by the journal, it mostly up to your personal preference. The main idea is to be consistent throughout your manuscript.

Keep in mind that there are many words that are spelled different in addition to *whilst/while* and *amongst/among*. Other words that I've come across include *colour/color*, *behaviour/behavior*, *labour/labor*.

A great tool, if you are using Microsoft Word, is the grammar checker where you can actually set your spelling preference and it will catch the majority of differences. [See here to set the language](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/check-spelling-and-grammar-in-a-different-language-667ba67a-a202-42fd-8596-edc1fa320e00), and [here for its use](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/check-grammar-spelling-and-more-in-word-0f43bf32-ccde-40c5-b16a-c6a282c0d251).

Comment: *Colour/color* and so forth are the British/American equivalents, not the British/Oxford equivalents that the question is about.

Comment: There's a special prize for misspelling "grammar" in an answer.

Comment: @StuartF Oops, thanks for catching that!